# Why does the query execute so much slower when all the columns involved are the same and only the where condition changes?

Tags: mysql, select

I have this query:

```
SELECT 1 AS InputIndex,
       IF(TRIM(DeviceInput1Name = '', 0, IF(INSTR(DeviceInput1Name, '|') > 0, 2, 1)) AS InputType,
       (SELECT Value1_1 FROM devicevalues WHERE DeviceID = devices.DeviceID ORDER BY ValueTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS InputValueLeft,
       (SELECT Value1_2 FROM devicevalues WHERE DeviceID = devices.DeviceID ORDER BY ValueTime DESC LIMIT 1) AS InputValueRight
  FROM devices
 WHERE DeviceIMEI = 'Some_Search_Value';
```

This completes fairly quickly (in up to 0.01 seconds). However, running the same query with `WHERE` clause as such

```
 WHERE DeviceIMEI = 'Some_Other_Search_Value';
```

makes it run for upwards of 14 seconds! Some search values finish very quickly, while others run way too long.

If I run `EXPLAIN` on either query, I get the following:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | devices      | ref   | DeviceIMEI    | DeviceIMEI | 28      | const |    1 | Using where |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | devicevalues | index | DeviceID,More | ValueTime  | 9       | NULL  |    1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | devicevalues | index | DeviceID,More | ValueTime  | 9       | NULL  |    1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Also, here's the actual number of records, just so it's clear:

```
mysql> select count(*) from devicevalues inner join devices using(DeviceID) where devices.DeviceIMEI = 'Some_Search_Value';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1017946 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.17 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from devicevalues inner join devices using(DeviceID) where devices.DeviceIMEI = 'Some_Other_Search_Value';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   306100 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Any ideas why changing a search value in the `WHERE` clause would cause the query to execute so slowly, even when the number of physical records to search through is lower?

Note there is no need for you to rewrite the query, just explain why the above happens.

**UPDATE:** I have tried running two separate queries instead of one with dependent subqueries to get the information I need (first I select `DeviceID` from `devices` by `DeviceIMEI`, then select from `devicevalues` by `DeviceID` I got from the previous query) and all queries return instantly. I suppose the only solution is to run these queries in a transaction, so I'll be making a stored procedure to do this. This, however, still doesn't answer my question which puzzles me.

Comment: what is the performance like if you remove the selects from your select. Just to narrow down the cause?

Comment: Removing dependent subqueries, the query returned in less than 0.01 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, **the query is the same**, and only the searched value changes.

There are three real possibilities as I can see, the first much likelier than the others:

1. The fast query only *appears* to be fast. And that's why it is in the MySQL query cache already. Try disabling the cache, running with NO_SQL_CACHE, or run the slow query twice. If the second way round runs in 0.01s instead of 14s, you'll know this is the case.
2. One query has to look way more records than the other. An IMEI may have lots of rows in devicevalues, another might have next no none. Apparently you are in such a condition, and what makes this unlikely is (apart from the times involved) the fact that it is the slower IMEI which actually has *less* matches.
3. The slow query is indeed slow. This means that a particular subset of data is hard to locate or hard to retrieve. The first may be due to an overdue reindexing or to filesystem fragmentation of very large indexes. The second can also be due to fragmentation of the tablespace, or to other condition which splits up records (for example the database is [partitioned](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)). A search in a small partition is wont to be faster than a search in a large partition.

But the time differences involved aren't equal in the three cases, and a 1400x difference seems to me an unlikely consequence of (2) or (3). The first possibility seems way more appealing.

**Update** you seem not to be using indexes on your subqueries. Have you an index such as

```
CREATE INDEX dv_ndx ON devicevalues(DeviceID, ValueTime);
```

If you can, you can try a covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX dv_ndx ON devicevalues(DeviceID, ValueTime, Value1_1, Value1_2);
```

Comment: I don't use query cache, so #1 is not the reason. #2 is not the reason because of what you said yourself. #3 is not the reason because the database I'm working on is synced hourly with another database and everything gets deleted, then written back, table by table, which means that the tables couldn't be fragmented. `DeviceID, ValueTime` index exists. The covering index I can't really do because it would be rather huge and I'd need eight of them for this to work (there are columns from Value1_1 and Value1_2 through Value8_1 and Value8_2). It's a rather poorly designed database.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that  1017946  is equivalent to the number of rows returned by your very first query.Your first query returns all rows from devices with some correlated queries,your count query returns all common rows between the 2 tables.If this is so the problem might be cardinality issues namely some_other_values constitute a much larger proportion of the rows in your first query than some_value so Mysql chooses a table scan.

Comment: I have tried rewriting the query to use `INNER JOIN` instead of dependent subqueries, which means I only get common rows now, but the problem persists.